# google sheets function gives weird #NAME? error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

[image: Screenshot of error]
I get this error from my query(import... ) function all the time on just one google sheet.  The work around is to delete the letter o from the formula, wait 10 seconds and then put the o back in.  Is there a way to solve this without having to remove the letter o.  This is the equivalent of turning it off and on again.

Here are a list of suggestions that didn't work.
1. Removing the custom getLink() function and wrapping it in an iferror function.

Comment: Could you please share the code related to `getLink()`?

Answer (score 0):

error is caused by the custom `getlink()` function inside importrange that gets timed out

try wrapping it into `IFERROR` and repeat it:

```
=IFERROR(query(imp....)), query(imp...)))
```

Comment: I did that and took out the getLink() functoin by typing the link directly in it.  It didnt' work